# MeGUI InterFrame - In-between frames are horrible

Tags: conversion, video-conversion, video-encoding, avisynth, megui

My original file is at 23.976 fps, I used MeGUI with [InterFrame](http://www.spirton.com/convert-videos-to-60fps/) to convert it to 60fps. Well, it successfully converted it into 59.940 fps, but a lot of in-between frames are horrible. I discovered that it happens when the movement of the object is intense, for example in the image, an explosion.

> **Original 23.976 FPS**
>
> > [image]
>
> **Converted 59.940 FPS**
>
> > [image]

This is my avs script.

```
LoadPlugin("C:\Program Files (x86)\MeGUI_2624_x86\tools\lsmash\LSMASHSource.dll")
LSMASHVideoSource("24FPS.mp4")

Cores=2
SetMemoryMax(512)
SetMTMode(3,Cores)

PluginPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MeGUI_2624_x86\tools\avisynth_plugin\"
LoadPlugin(PluginPath+"svpflow1.dll")
LoadPlugin(PluginPath+"svpflow2.dll")
Import(PluginPath+"InterFrame2.avsi")

SetMTMode(2)
ConvertToYV12()

#deinterlace
#crop
#denoise
#resize

InterFrame(Cores=Cores, GPU=true)
```

Comment: That looks similar to the content created by saving jpeg files with a high compression setting (aiming at a small file).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I clearly made a boo-boo. I fixed it by replacing `InterFrame(Cores=Cores, GPU=true)` with `InterFrame(Tuning="Animation", Cores=Cores, GPU=true)`.